# Using the Camera class with Flex Mobile Framework and Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I like so many others is trying to implement a barcode scanner for my Flex Mobile app using the zxing actionscript library.  My issue is that I'm having a heck of a time just getting the camera to display properly on the actual device.  Running the app on the desktop with a webcam shows the video feed just fine.  Below is what i get on my Galaxy Nexus and similar on the Nexus 7.

[image: on the galaxy nexus]

I've been primarily working off of this example but have taken suggestions from other sites as well: 
http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-a-qr-code-reader-in-flex-on-android

Everything produces the same wacky feed to the Video Object.  Anybody know what I could do to correct this?

Here's my code in its current form which is just trying to get a clear picture at this point (no barcode junk yet):

scanner2.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:bs="com.expologic.barcodescanner"
    title="Scanner" creationComplete="init(event)">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        import com.expologic.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner;

        private var bs:BarcodeScanner;

        private function init(e:Event):void {

            bs = new BarcodeScanner();
            bs.horizontalCenter = 0;
            bs.verticalCenter = 0;
            bs.height = 480;
            bs.width = 640;

            addElement(bs);

            //To add a target to the center of the screen
            var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            this.addElement(uic);

            uic.width = uic.height = 275;
            uic.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xFF0000);
            uic.graphics.drawRect(0,0,275,275);

            uic.horizontalCenter = uic.verticalCenter = 0;

        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>



</s:View>
```

BarcodeScanner.as

```
package com.expologic.barcodescanner
    {

        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.media.Camera;
        import flash.media.Video;

        import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

        public class BarcodeScanner extends SpriteVisualElement
        {

            private var _video:Video;

            public function BarcodeScanner()
            {

                this.height = 480;
                this.width = 640;

                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _addToStage);

            }

            private function _addToStage(e:Event):void {
                _setupCamera();
            }


            private function _setupCamera():void
            {

                if(!_video)
                {
                    _video = new Video(640, 480);
                    addChild(_video);
                }

                if(Camera.isSupported)
                {
                    var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
                    cam.setQuality(0, 100);
                    cam.setMode(640, 480, 30, false);

                    _video.attachCamera(cam);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` in your app.xml, that solved the problem for me and I'm also using the Galaxy Nexus.
Regards
Joko

Comment: Ah! This works!  I did find that going back to AIR 3.1 on the device resolved the issue as well but of course Android wants to keep auto updating AIR.  Somebody should tell Adobe to do this in the Tour de Flex mobile app because it was happening in the camera example there too!

Answer (score 1):

I am not understand the exact issue, but Try to add permissions listed in the below link:

> [zxing barcode scanner autofocus issue on reading second qr code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126045/zxing-barcode-scanner-autofocus-issue-on-reading-second-qr-code/14455824#14455824)

Comment: Already had camera and autofocus as permissions but I'll try the rest later tonight.

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  Still the gray jumble mess.